# mongoose - querying for array value in subdocument

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am using mongoose. I have the following documents in my database:

```
question: {
    "id": "1",
        "answers": [
        {
            "id": "11",
            "deletedAt": "2021-05-28T20:23:30.409Z",
        }
    }
},
question: {
    "id": "2",
        "answers": [
         {
            "id": "22",
            "deletedAt": null,
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to construct a query, which returns all the anwsers, which have a deletedAt value, so are not null.
I tried the following:

```
Question.find({ "answers.deletedAt": { $ne: null }});
```

This returns all Questions. However, I would not just like to return only the answers, but just the onces which have a value in the deletedAt field.
So sticking to the example above, I would like this output:

```
{
    "id": "11",
    "deletedAt": "2021-05-28T20:23:30.409Z",
}
```

I would be very thankful for any kind of help!

Comment: If one question has 2 answers, one has deletedAt null and the other does not. What result would you expect in that case?

Comment: I would expect the answer which has been deleted to be returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation

- `$filter` to filter non null deletedAt form the array and `$set` helps to add as a new field
- `$match` to remove empty array documents

here is the code

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$set": {
      "answers": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$answers",
          "cond": {
            $ne: [ "$$this.deletedAt", null ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $ne: [ "$answers", [] ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bPAKQWTXbNi)**

Comment: This returns the error: Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$set'

Comment: What is your mongo db version?

Comment: Mongo Version 3.6.8. Mongoose Version 5.11.18

Comment: `$set` was introduced in 4.2 mongodb. You can use `$addFields` instead of `$set`

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!!